# How to use the exclude_files regex in cpplint?

Tags: regex, google-style-guide, cpplint

I am using cpplint to check my sourcode agains the google style guide.

**Cpplint's help says:**

```
cpplint.py supports per-directory configurations specified in CPPLINT.cfg
    files. CPPLINT.cfg file can contain a number of key=value pairs.
    Currently the following options are supported:

    "exclude_files" allows to specify a regular expression to be matched against
    a file name. If the expression matches, the file is skipped and not run
    through liner.

Example file:
        filter=-build/include_order,+build/include_alpha
        exclude_files=.*\.cc

    The above example disables build/include_order warning and enables
    build/include_alpha as well as excludes all .cc from being
    processed by linter, in the current directory (where the .cfg
    file is located) and all sub-directories.
```

**How I use cpplint:**

I use `cpplint` by this command to check all files in my source folder:
`cpplint src/*.c`

Well there is one special file `foo.cc` which must not be checked. So I tried to create a `CPPLIN.cfg` to use the `exclude_files` property. My file looks like this:

```
set noparent
filter=-build/include_dir
exclude_files=foo.cc
```

Nevertheless `foo.cc` is still checked.

**What I have already tried to do:**

I tried  `exclude_files=/.*\.cc/`. This should exclude all files ending with *.cc. Nevertheless all files are still checked.

I tried to remove my `filter` from the file. This caused more errors than before. So I am now sure that my `CPPLINT.cfg` file is found by cpplint.

**Question:**

How to use the exclude_files regex in cpplint correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out apparently that the doc is wrong: `exclude_files` only excludes files in the same directory as `CPPLINT.cfg`, not in subdirectories.  See https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/220

So the solution would be to create `src/CPPLINT.cfg` and put `exclude_files=.*\.cc` in it.